# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier X. Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to import a module for my project but keep encountering an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "vue-filter-date-format".
Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

So far I've tried to use the relative path, which admittedly does work (until I face problems with exports apparently not existing later down the line, this also includes editing outside files that have been installed), but I'm trying to stick to the examples of how to implement them. The packages containing the modules have been installed through NPM.

Here's the statement being made:

```
import VueFilterDateFormat from 'vue-filter-date-format';
```

As a result of this I get the error.

Comment: Are you using vue-cli at all or it's vanilla vue.js?

Looks like you are trying to import module in html or non-node file.

Comment: @Deda vanilla vue.js

Comment: Then that's it, you cannot import node module in vanilla js. You need vue-cli.

Comment: @Deda I see, I've installed the cli and imported the project folder, and can see the dependencies now, would I have to build in the cli somehow? I'm not seeing anything in the tasks area?

Comment: I don't know what is `tasks` area in your project, you just have to include modules in main.js and for development use `npm run serve` and for production you'll have to build with `npm run build` and in dist folder is your project(vue-cli 3)